# Like Button text wrong? Might have idea

Tags: button, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

My problem is that when you press the like button on my site it says, you want to like an "untitled document" not [my site](http://thisismypic.com/).  I think the reason is that in the early days of testing I forgot to remove the place holder text of "untitled document" and put in something like "This is my pic!, Celebrating people's genius one pic at a time".  so now each time somebody likes the page it says.  "untitled document".

Is there a way to make it display the current title.

Comment: The code on your site works if you're talking about the one at the top of the page.

Answer (score 3):

The title seems to have updated correctly when you run this through the [url linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fthisismypic.com%2F). Using the linter refreshes the data Facebook has cached about your website (note that it can only be used once every hour). If you do not see your information updated, consider adding [Open Graph Tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to explicitly tell Facebook which information to use for your page.

Additionally, adding yourself as an admin using these tags will allow you to edit the page manually (via Facebook) in the future.

Comment: Great advice and yes I did find it to be a cache issue.  Also Thanks for the advice on the Open Graph tags I'm going to ad those to my sites also great Idea, I had forgotten that I wanted to do that.